# Revert a perforce submit which is also the first commit to the branch

Tags: perforce

I had garbage at the end of my integration command and ended up doing something like this:
p4 integrate  //head/test-integrate-1.0/... //head/test-integrate-2.0/...clear

So,  I now have test-integrate-2.0 with all files with a 'clear' in their names, e.g. A renamed to Aclear in test-integrate-2.0
Now, this is also the first submit to test-integrate-2.0.
My question is what is the best method to revert this integration and redo it with all the 'correct' revision history intact.

Answer (score 1):

A simple, but effective, approach is:

```
p4 delete //head/test-integrate-2.0/...clear
p4 submit
```

then

```
p4 integrate //head/test-integrate-1.0/... //head/test-integrate-2.0/...
p4 submit
```

You'll have a permanent record of the files that were created then deleted by the unintentional integration in your repository, but it shouldn't interfere with anything.